# Still receiving no First Input Delay (FID) or Interaction to Next Paint (INP) across website under Pagespeed Insights

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint, first-input-delay

This issue appeared more than six months ago which, from what reading I could find, seemed to suggest that there was not enough data to provide metrics for FID or INP. Although that may not be correct. Data for the Time to First Byte (TTFB) appears to be absent, as well.

The site in question can be viewed at https://www.wanstor.com.

This lack of information has persisted, and I cannot reason why the subdomain is not returning this data. Even with poor performance it should be able to return these metrics, unless I have misunderstood. The URL above represents the homepage which must surely have interaction/s from users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a nice third-party tool to view your historical CrUX data:
https://www.rumvision.com/tools/core-web-vitals-history/www.wanstor.com/origin/mobile/?path=/

[image: CrUX historical data]

Here you can see for the total origin there are many weeks (particularly recently) where there is insufficient data for FID and INP.

Switching to the home page it is even worse (and includes TTFB):

[image: Home Page CrUX Historical data]

Going back to Google's CrUX data, if you run this query on BigQuery to look at the latest available data (Nov 2023 at the time of writing):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `chrome-ux-report.materialized.device_summary`
WHERE date = "2023-10-01" AND
origin = 'https://www.wanstor.com'
```

You can see you are in the top 10,000,000 ranking bucket which is close to the outer limit of sites with enough users to appear in CrUX (12 million desktop sites and 15 million mobile sites at the time of writing).

As not ALL users will interact with static websites it is not surprising that FID and INP have less availability and fail to meet the threshold sooner than the other metrics, as appears to be the case here.

So, all evidence points to the fact that there is [not enough data to meet CrUX's eligibility criteria](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology#popularity-eligibility) (the exact value for which, Chrome does not disclose).

Comment: Thanks for this, Barry - would performance of the system on which this is hosted possibly help to improve this situation? I believe you mentioned the server in previous feedback on a similar query I had (the account login email for which I am now battling to find). 

I am still fighting for internal resource to overhaul the app on which this website is hosted and this feedback is very positive in terms of being able to point towards a prospective solution or part thereof.

Comment: Only in so much as performance general improves usability so may lead to more users but whether that's enough to give you enough users to cross the popularity eligibility threshold is probably a bit of a stretch. However, when FID and INP are not available (as I say this often happens with static sites) the CWV is still flagged as "Passed" so this is not something to be concerned with. If you are generally interested if you have a responsiveness issue you can collect your own RUM data but based on the history where it is available it doesn't look like you do have a responsiveness issue.

Comment: That's great information, thanks Barry.